# Is there something wrong with the code I made?

Tags: java, set-intersection, set-difference

So our project is all about sets and it should display the union, intersection, difference and I am having doubts on my code because in the example given to us by our teacher, the elements of the set was already given and in the output there is no "null" result in the union and intersection BUT our challenge is to have the elements to be user input AND in my code there is a "null" result in my union and intersection. Is that okay?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
    a.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[5]));
    for () {
       //scan code...
    }





    Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<Integer>();
    b.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[5]));
    for () {
       //scan code...
    }

    // UNION

    Set<Integer> union = new HashSet<Integer>(a);
    union.addAll(b);
    System.out.print("\nUnion of the two Set: ");
    System.out.println(union);


    // INTERSECTION

    Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<Integer>(a);
    intersection.retainAll(b);
    System.out.print("Intersection of the two Set: ");
    System.out.println(intersection);


    // DIFFERENCE

    Set<Integer> difference = new HashSet<Integer>(a);
    difference.removeAll(b);
    System.out.print("Difference of the two Set: ");
    System.out.println(difference);

}
```

OUTPUT: (TEACHER'S GIVEN CODE!)

Union of the two Set[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]

Intersection of the two Set[0, 1, 3, 4]

Difference of the two Set[2, 8, 9]

MY OUTPUT:

Set A :

3 4 2 1 0

Set B :

7 4 1 9 8

Union of the two Set: [null, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]

Intersection of the two Set: [null, 1, 4]

Difference of the two Set: [0, 2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

You have the null because of these two lines in your code :

```
        a.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[5]));
        b.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[5]));
```

Just remove these two lines and your code should work.

Comment: @Hensely This is probably your solution.  But do be sure you ask yourself these questions (and find satisfactory answers for them) before you move on: 1) How were those lines causing the problem? 2) what were you hoping/expecting to accomplish with them? 3) why did you _think_ they were necessary (and why are they, in fact, _not_ necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @theincrediblethor, but as an explanation...

You are initializing a Set as if it were an array.  Initially a Set is empty, and an array is uninitialized.  You don't want to put "empty" Integers [null, null, null, null, null] in the Set, they will just stay there even when you add the real Integers on input.

Since Sets don't allow duplicates, 4 of the empty Integers are dropped upon add.

So you are left with 1 null and all of your input.

Answer (score 0):

In your line

```
a.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[5]));
```

new Integer[5] is creating an array of 5 null values [ null,null,null,null,null ]

Arrays.asList() just turns it into a Collection(List) of 5 null values

a.addAll() adds all the elements of your Collection into your Set and, as the values are unique, you only add one null

So you just have to remove that line, same for Set b

Try this code and you will see the step by step

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[5];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
        a.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(a);
        a.add(1);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

it prints

[image]